# Connection error due to an error in SQL connector configuration

Tags: ballerina

When I run the following code,

```
import ballerina/http;
import ballerina/sql;
import ballerinax/mysql;
import ballerinax/mysql.driver as _;

type isValid record {
    boolean valid;
    string nic;
};

type Person record {
    string mic;
    @sql:Column {name: "firstname"}
    string firstName;
    @sql:Column {
        name: "lastname"
    }
    string lastName;
};

configurable string database = ?;
configurable string username = ?;
configurable string host = ?;

mysql:Client mysqlEp = check new (host = host, user = username, database = database);

service / on new http:Listener(9090) {
    resource function get checkNic/[string nic]() returns isValid|error? {

        Person|error person = check mysqlEp->queryRow(`select * from nic_details where nic=${nic.trim()}`);

        if (person is error) {
            isValid result = {
                valid: false,
                nic: nic
            };
            return result;
        } else {
            isValid result = {
                valid: true,
                nic: nic
            };
            return result;
        }
    }

    resource function get path() {

    }
}
```

getting the following error:

```
error: Error in SQL connector configuration: Failed to initialize pool: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server. Caused by :Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server. Caused by :Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server. Caused by :Connection refused
```

I gave the port correctly which is 3306 (default), and also Xampp shows that the MySQL server is running on the port 3306.
Furthermore, I gave `localhost` as host.
What could be the cause of the above error?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the vscode instance is running on a remote server. When you refer `localhost` there, it refers to that remote server. Not your local machine.
That's why you cannot access your local MySQL instance via vscode here.
You have to have your MySQL instance in a place which is accessible via public internet (ex: Amazon RDS) and provide that IP/hostname to the MySQL client here.